# Is integrating $e^{iz^{2}}$, along the real axis in the complex plane the same as integrating the riemann integral of $e^{x^2}$?

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

In the title, $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. More specific to my problem, I am hoping that 
$\int_{0}^{R}e^{iz^{2}}dz=\int_{0}^{R}e^{x^{2}}dx$. Maybe this is obvious but I want to make sure.

Comment: No,  why would they be the same? The title and the text describe different questions!

Comment: oops, I will fix that. I am a bit confused about the relationship between integrating along one axis of the complex plane and riemann integration. I have a theorem from class that if $\gamma(t)=t$, $t\in[a,b]$, then $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$, the riemann integral. Is there a way to apply this here?

Comment: The integrand in the left hand side is bounded by 1, but the integrand on the right is unbounded.

Comment: Just to note that your theorem above says $\int f(z) = \int f(x)$ under those conditions, not $\int f(iz) = \int f(x)$.

Comment: @copper.hat What would change if the integrand were bounded, say if it were $e^{-x^{2}}$?

Comment: Why? You need to have some reason to justify what you are doing. Just guessing without some underlying reasoning is unlikely to produce anything useful.  Note that in both integrals, you are integrating along the real axis.

Comment: I was following up "The integrand in the left hand side is bounded by 1, but the integrand on the right is unbounded." but I guess you just said this to illustrate why they couldnt be equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are not the same. The $i$ before $z^2$ (that is not present before $x^2$) changes things.

For one, the modulus of $e^{i\theta}$ is always one whenever $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, and since your integral is along the real line, $z$ (and thus $z^2$) assumes only real values.